# No submitblock in altcoin?

Tags: altcoin, bitcoin-core-development, sending

I'm trying to figure out how I'd submit a block in many alt-coins. I originally found this issue in bbqcoin but have since found it in many others. I have bbqcoin (and others) installed from gihub source on Ubuntu 12.04.4

```
root@ubuntu-hp:~# bbqcoind help
addmultisigaddress <nrequired> <'["key","key"]'> [account]
backupwallet <destination>
dumpprivkey <bbqcoinaddress>
encryptwallet <passphrase>
getaccount <bbqcoinaddress>
getaccountaddress <account>
getaddressesbyaccount <account>
getbalance [account] [minconf=1]
getblock <hash> [decompositions]
getblockcount
getblockhash <index>
getconnectioncount
getdifficulty
getgenerate
gethashespersec
getinfo
getmemorypool [data]
getmininginfo
getnetworkhashps [blocks]
getnewaddress [account]
getpeerinfo
getrawmempool
getreceivedbyaccount <account> [minconf=1]
getreceivedbyaddress <bbqcoinaddress> [minconf=1]
gettransaction <txid> [decompositions]
getwork [data]
getworkex [data, coinbase]
help [command]
importprivkey <bbqcoinprivkey> [label]
keypoolrefill
listaccounts [minconf=1]
listreceivedbyaccount [minconf=1] [includeempty=false]
listreceivedbyaddress [minconf=1] [includeempty=false]
listsinceblock [blockhash] [target-confirmations]
listtransactions [account] [count=10] [from=0]
move <fromaccount> <toaccount> <amount> [minconf=1] [comment]
sendfrom <fromaccount> <tobbqcoinaddress> <amount> [minconf=1] [comment] [comment-to]
sendmany <fromaccount> {address:amount,...} [minconf=1] [comment]
sendrawtx <hex string>
sendtoaddress <bbqcoinaddress> <amount> [comment] [comment-to]
setaccount <bbqcoinaddress> <account>
setgenerate <generate> [genproclimit]
setmininput <amount>
settxfee <amount>
signmessage <bbqcoinaddress> <message>
stop
validateaddress <bbqcoinaddress>
verifymessage <bbqcoinaddress> <signature> <message>
```

Best I can figure, the closest thing would be sendrawtx.. but that can't be right, can it? I'm thinking at this point I should have taken advantage of the checkout feature, but it's hard to tell what version each coin is on.

Edit: I've found that many coins have this issue as described here: https://github.com/Crypto-Expert/stratum-mining/issues/72

So looks like the solution is to build it yourself, there is a hail-mary workaround which might do the trick but is heavily undocumented. I found reference that you can submit a block through getblocktemplate, https://github.com/moopless/stratum-mining-litecoin/issues/48

When trying with some data I go a json parse error.. has anyone used getblocktemplate submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, took some doing but I figured it out!

It seems there a lot of which do not have submitblock in the source. Whether this is intended (mining advantages vs noobs) or just pure incompetence is not sure, but the solution requires minimal changes to the source.

I found this which should help if you're having this issue: https://github.com/earthcoinproject/earthcoin/commit/0b862e499e05386e333563656f84e99bad1b0290

Hope this helps another frustrated developer :)